# How are $\pi/4$ and $3\pi/4$ solutions to $\sec^2 \theta -2 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How are $\pi/4$ and $3\pi/4$ solutions to $\sec^2 \theta -2 = 0$

Please show work. I added two to both sides and then took the square root of each side to get $\sec\theta$ = $\sqrt2$

Where on the unit circle does $\sqrt2$ equal $\pi/4$?

Comment: Nowhere, the problem says that the *secant* of $\pi/4$ is $\sqrt{2}$, not that $\pi/4=\sqrt 2$, which is false.

**Hint:** Remember $\sec\theta=1/\cos\theta$, so that if $\sec\theta =x$ this is the same as $\cos\theta ={1\over x}$.

Comment: Cosine is √2/2. If I dvide it by one I get the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that is accurate, ${\sqrt{2}\over 2}$ is just another way of writing ${1\over \sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Indeed, after I do my work. If I go backwards. I still do not see how √2 quals pi/4

Comment: Ok. I see it now.

Answer (score 4):

If $\sec^2\theta -2 = 0$ then $\sec^2\theta = 2$ and so $\sec\theta = \pm\sqrt{2}$.

Given that $\sec\theta$ is the reciprocal of $\cos\theta$ we have
$$\sec\theta = \pm \sqrt{2} \iff \frac{1}{\cos\theta} = \pm\sqrt{2} \iff \cos\theta = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
You have two equations to solve: $\cos\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\cos\theta = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Solve these separately.

**Remember:** Trigonometric equations, if they have solutions, have lots of them. For example:

$$\sin(0)=\sin(\pi)=\sin(2\pi)=0$$

Make sure to find all of the solutions in the range that you have been asked.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the graph from [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sec%28theta%29) website.

However, $(\sqrt{2})^2=2$, and the equation is not about secant, it's about secant *squared.*

Therefore, what you really have when you add both sides i
s $\sec^2{\theta}=2.$

To get $\sec{\theta}$ rather than $\sec^2{\theta}$, we take the square root of both sides, $\sec{\theta}=\sqrt{2}$.

And you already showed us that $\sec{\theta}$ can be $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: $\sec{\theta}=2$ definitely has solutions: [see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sec%28theta%29%3D2).

Comment: It certainly isn’t true that $\sec\theta$ never equals $2$. Indeed, that’s the same as cosine equaling $1/2$, which you know all about.

Comment: Ha ha ha... it's been a long week